# Anisotropic Rician distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bessel-functions

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution), if you have two independant Gaussian/normal random variables $X \sim N\left(\mu_X=\nu\cos\theta,\sigma_X^2\right)$ and $Y \sim N\left(\mu_Y=\nu \sin\theta,\sigma_Y^2\right)$. With joint distribution:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y }
      \mathrm{e}^{
        -\frac{1}{2}\left[
          (\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X})^2 +
          (\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y})^2 
        \right]
      }$$

If $\sigma=\sigma_x=\sigma_y$, you can get the distribution of $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ with the Rice or Rician distribution:

$$R \sim \mathrm{Rice}\left(|\nu|,\sigma\right)$$

The distribution is $$f_Z(z\mid\nu,\sigma) = \frac{z}{\sigma^2}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-(z^2+\nu^2)}
{2\sigma^2}}I_0\left(\frac{z\nu}{\sigma^2}\right)$$and its mean is: $$\mu_1^{'}=  \sigma  \sqrt{\pi/2}L_{1/2}(-\nu^2/2\sigma^2)$$

The derivation is given in example 6-16 of [this textbook](https://my.ece.utah.edu/%7Enpatwari/ece6962/Papoulis_pillai_6_2_and_6_3.pdf).

My question is the following:

**How to derive a compact expression of the mean of the same distribution with $\sigma_x \ne \sigma_y $ ?**

I've try to calculate it with Mathematica but failed:
[image]
If I substitute the $\sigma_Y=1*\sigma$ by $\sigma_Y=2*\sigma$ the integral cannot be calculated.